# Random Variables and Expected Values

Tags: probability, random-variables

X and Y are random variables with identical distributions. How do you prove/disprove X = Y and E(X) = E(Y). I am not looking for a ready-made answer. I would appreciate it if someone would point me in the right direction towards the appropriate resource.

Comment: Do you mean to use the word test, rather than prove?

Comment: Please accept the answer if you are satisfied by pressing the tick. That way other users would be more willing to help you. Please can you also consider doing the same to other questions you asked?

Comment: I meant prove. I still need help!

Comment: Same distirbutiom does not mean X=Y, but EX=EY holds.

Comment: @user100503 Lost1 and I have both addressed the issue of proving E(X)=E(Y) if they have the same distribution. Its true by definition! The expected value is a property of a distribution, so if both have the same distribution, then they have the same expected values.

Comment: How do you disprove X = Y?

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to prove by counterexample.

Comment: Ok, then please close out this question if you have no further issues with our comments and the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the [Kolmorgov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). Use one of your datasets (X or Y) as the "reference distribution" and the other as the "test" distribution and see if you get a significant result..if so, then they are different.

Also note that if X and Y have the same distribution, then that implies that E(X)=E(Y), so this covers tha t issues as well. To test just the equality of means, you can use a number of "tests of location" for this purpose. This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_test) has a nice list.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: @user100503 if this helped you, please accept to close out this question. Thanks :)